# Method doesn't work when transferred to another Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a method in my "MasterView" () class that parses .json data from a URL then populates a table view with the information. In order to be more organized and group the method with other needed methods I attempted to move it into another NSOject class but it didn't work; no errors, no exceptions the table view simply doesn't populate.

Here is the original method in the "Master Class"

```
- (void) fetchPosts:  
{
    NSError *error;

    NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

    NSArray *objects = [[json objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"children"];

    arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *object in objects) {
        NSString *title = [[object objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"title"];

        //Post is just a random NSObject Class
        Post *post = [[Post alloc] init];
        post.title = title;
        [arr addObject:post];
    }

    NSLog(@"Called");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The Edited Method in the other class:

```
- (void) fetchPosts:(NSURL *)myURL withPostArray:(NSMutableArray*)postArr andTableView: (UITableView*)tableView
{
   NSLog(@"CAlled");

    NSError *error;

    NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

    NSArray *objects = [[json objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"children"];

    postArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *object in objects) {
        NSString *title = [[object objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"title"];

        Post *post = [[Post alloc] init];
        post.title = title;
        [postArr addObject:post];
    }


    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

The original Method that works is called: `[self fetchPosts:];` the other is: `[MyClass fetchPosts:myUrl withPostArray:arr andTableView:self.tableView];`

I edited some information out to make it more readable so please let me know if there is any mistakes.

MyClass.h:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Setting the datasource in MasterView:

```
//In ViewDidLoad
_delegate = myClass;

self.tableView.dataSource = _delegate;
self.tableView.delegate = _delegate;

//In .h 

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyClass *delegate;
```

Im getting nothing from the compiler when I call `[MyClass fetchPosts:myUrl withPostArray:arr andTableView:self.tableView];`

Comment: Without reading the source, my guess is that some pointer is nil because you didn't initialize it.  Or, as Mohannad suggests, if the method isn't getting called at all it's likely you did not set a delegate pointer properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table view doesn't populate, then the table view is not getting the needed data through the data source.

It's possible that you didn't set the `dataSource` of your `tableView` to the new `NSObject` you created, or that `MasterView` is still the `dataSource` of the `tableView`.

Also, make sure that this method is actually called and the passed `tableView` is the one presented in the view.

---

**Edit:** You have three solutions:

1. Assign the data source to the new object you created so it handles updating the table view with data, since it now has the actual data.
2. Adjust that method to return the parsed data to the `MasterView` and it calls `[self.tableView reloadData]`. **But this is not really good from MVC's point of view.**
3. The third option requires you to create a `UIVieController` to handle your `MasterView` and it should be the `dataSource` for the table view. The view controller should call the said method from the new object, to retrieve the data and update the table view. *i.e. like the 2nd solution, but a view controller will call the method and not the `MasterView`*.

Comment: Im kind of confused on what to do based on what you said but the `self.tableView` is a property of "Master" and it's datasource is the "MasterView." Also I noticed the compiler does say "Called" like it should when the method is called.

Comment: Then it's the problem of the `dataSource` being set to the wrong object. The `dataSource` of the table view is the object responsible for providing the sections, rows and all related data to the table view.

Comment: Ok I think I get what you're saying but I have never had to manipulate the dataSource of anything like this before. I tried adding `@property (strong, nonatomic) myClass *delegate;` to the `MasterView` then `self.tableView.dataSource = self.delegate;` I unhinged the datasource and delegate from the nib as well. The tableView still does not populate. I also have 2 errors when I assign the data source: "assigning to id<UITableViewDataSource> from incompatible type myclass." Side note: I did everything for the delegate as same as the datasource I didn't feel the need to show both in the comment

Comment: 'UITableView` expects `dataSource` to conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, and `delegate`to conform to `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. After that, you implement the methods of these protocols in the new class. **Since** you've previously implemented those methods in `MasterView` just copy them in the new class.

Comment: Ok. I changed the interface in myClass to `@interface myClass : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` and then `self.tableView.dataSource = self.delegate` and `self.tableView.delagate = self.delegate` in the Master Class, `self.delagate` being the property in my previous comment. I am still not getting a response from my compiler when I call `[MyClass fetchPosts:myUrl withPostArray:arr andTableView:self.tableView];`

Comment: Some points in mind: **1-** Did you actually set `MasterView.delegate = myClass;`?, **2-** Make sure the `tableView` is not `nil`. **3-** Make sure the `UITableViewDataSource`'s methods are implemented right. If none of these worked out, consider updating your answer with the class, so we can check it.

Comment: Please look at my edit. Im getting nothing from my compiler so I don't think that anything is happening when I call the methods from MyClass.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31212/discussion-between-mohannad-a-hassan-and-tanner)